# Scraping for related news using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to **scrape** the Snopes fact-checking website using Scrapy. Here, I want to find out related news based on the user given input. User gives a word and Scrapy crawler will return related news. For example, if I enter NASA as input, Scrapy will give NASA related news. I tried but there is no output.

```
import scrapy

class fakenews(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "snopes5"
    allowed_domains = ["snopes.com"]
    start_urls = [
            "https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/category/science/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
            name1=input('Please Enter the search item you want for fake news: ')
            headers = response.xpath('//div[@class="media-body"]/h5').extract()
            headers = [c.strip().lower() for c in headers]
            if name1 in headers:
                print(response.xpath('//div[@class="navHeader"]/ul'))
                filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: What do you mean there is no output? could you post the log?

Comment: In code, output is save as html file but after running the crawler, no file is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one vital error in your code:

```
c=response.xpath('//div[@class="navHeader"]/ul')
if name1 in c:
    ...
```

here `c` end up being a `SelectorList` object and you are checking whether string `name` is in `SelectorList` object which of course will always be `False`.
To remedy this you need to extract your values:

```
c=response.xpath('//div[@class="navHeader"]/ul').extract()
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Additionally you probably would want to process the values to make matching more volatile:

```
headers = response.xpath('//div[@class="navHeader"]/ul').extract()
headers = [c.strip().lower() for c in headers]
if name1 in headers:
    ...
```

The above will ignore trailing and leading spaces as well as make everything lowercase for case-insensitive matching.

---

Your use case example:

```
headers = sel.xpath('//div[@class="media-body"]/h5/text()').extract() 
headers = [c.strip().lower() for c in headers]  
for header in headers: 
    if 'gorilla' in header: 
        print(f'yay matching header: "{header}"')
```

outputs:

```
yay matching header: "did this gorilla learn how to knit?"
```

Comment: I followed your instruction but still not getting any output.

Comment: Could you please check what I need to do to get output ? .

Comment: I've added an edit but you really should try to make some progress yourself, I explained everything you just need to put it together.